# selecting checkbox from checkbox list on condition

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

i have 5 checkboxlists, and each of the checkboxlists have the same 6 checkboxes.
i have to check these checkboxlists during `page_Load` under certain conditions. 
How do i do that.?

```
for (int j = 0; j < no_of_listitem; j++)
{
    SqlCommand check = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISGoal1, ISGoal2,ISGoal3, ISGoal4,ISGoal5 FROM PRM2011_EMPLOYEE_GOAL WHERE EmployeeID = '" + employeeid[j] + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader y = check.ExecuteReader();
    while (y.Read())
    {
        if (null != y && y.HasRows)
        {
            string yes_or_no = y["ISGoal1"].ToString();
            yes_or_no = yes_or_no.Trim();
            if (yes_or_no == "Yes")
            {
                CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Selected = true;
            }

            //else CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Selected = false;

            yes_or_no = y["ISGoal2"].ToString();
            yes_or_no = yes_or_no.Trim();
            if (yes_or_no == "Yes")
            {
                CheckBoxList2.Items[j].Selected = true;
            }
            //else CheckBoxList2.Items[j].Selected = false;

            yes_or_no = y["ISGoal3"].ToString();
            yes_or_no = yes_or_no.Trim();
            if (yes_or_no == "Yes")
            {
                CheckBoxList3.Items[j].Selected = true;
            }
            //else CheckBoxList3.Items[j].Selected = false;

            yes_or_no = y["ISGoal4"].ToString();
            yes_or_no = yes_or_no.Trim();
            if (yes_or_no == "Yes")
            {
                CheckBoxList4.Items[j].Selected = true;
            }
            //else CheckBoxList4.Items[j].Selected = false;

            yes_or_no = y["ISGoal5"].ToString();
            yes_or_no = yes_or_no.Trim();
            if (yes_or_no == "Yes")
            {
                CheckBoxList5.Items[j].Selected = true;
            }
            //else CheckBoxList5.Items[j].Selected = false;
        }
    }
    y.Close();
}
```

`employeeid[]` contains id of 6 employees.no_of_listitems is 6 which is the list of thses 6 employee ids.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with your CheckBoxList in it. Then, replace the code with something like this:

```
for(int z = 1; z <= checkboxLists.Count; z++)
{
    checkboxLists[z].Items[j].Selected = y["ISGoal" + z].ToString().Trim() == "yes";
}
```

Keep in mind though that this code is not type-safe. Normally, you'd want to avoid using string in your code and y["ISGoal"+z] might be null. If it is, the application will crash. This mean you want to make checks to make sure it's ok. Trying to make a ToString() or Trim() on null will make a NullPointerException. You might also want to change "yes" by bit in your database. It would be much more safe to work with. What if someone writes "true" instead of yes?

I hope it helps out. If you have any question, don't hesitate.

Comment: how do i create a list of checkboxlist? 
My application is such that noone is writing "Yes" or "No".the code is such that if the checkbox is selected then "Yes" will be updated in the database. but still, how else do u propose to handle the situation.

Comment: `List<CheckBoxList> checkboxLists = new List<CheckBoxList>(); checkboxLists.Add(CheckBoxList1);...`

Comment: By writing YES or NO in code, you use more space in your database for no reason. A bit will use less space and is a better idea. By making a list of CheckBoxList, you will be able to loop on each lists instead of copy and pasting the whole glob of code you've posted in your question.